# How to sort Map based on Value i.e. an Object having multiple properties

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have a pretty straight forward code to sort HashMap based on values not on keys (Copied from SO but the e.g. on SO was just sorting String where as I want to sort based on properties of Objects)

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class SortMapByValue
{
    public static boolean ASC = true;
    public static boolean DESC = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
Person person = new Person(21, "John", 174, "Doe");
    Person personTwo = new Person(19, "Michael", 154, "Jordan");
    Person personThree = new Person(22, "David", 184, "Sun");
    Person personFour = new Person(23, "Ian", 164, "Miller");
        // Creating dummy unsorted map
        Map<String, Person> unsortMap = new HashMap<>();
        unsortMap.put("B", person);
        unsortMap.put("A", personTwo);
        unsortMap.put("D", personThree);
        unsortMap.put("C", personFour);

        System.out.println("Before sorting......");
        printMap(unsortMap);

        System.out.println("After sorting ascending order......");
        Map<String, Person> sortedMapAsc = sortByComparator(unsortMap, ASC);
        printMap(sortedMapAsc);


        System.out.println("After sorting descindeng order......");
        Map<String, Person> sortedMapDesc = sortByComparator(unsortMap, DESC);
        printMap(sortedMapDesc);

    }

    private static Map<String, Person> sortByComparator(Map<String, Person> unsortMap, final boolean order)
    {

        List<Entry<String, Person>> list = new LinkedList<>(unsortMap.entrySet());

        // Sorting the list based on values
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Person>>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<String, Person> o1, Entry<String, Person> o2)
            {
                if (order)
                {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                }
                else
                {
                    return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());

                }
            }
        });

        // Maintaining insertion order with the help of LinkedList
        Map<String, Person> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Entry<String, Person> entry : list)
        {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }

    public static void printMap(Map<String, Person> map)
    {
        for (Entry<String, Person> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "+ entry.getValue().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Person Class:

```
public class Person implements Comparable{

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private int height;
    private String lastname;

    public Person(int age, String name, int height, String lastname) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        Person country=(Person) arg0;
        return (this.getAge() < country.getAge() ) ? -1: (this.getAge() > country.getAge() ) ? 1:0;
    }        

}
```

Now if you copy paste the code to your IDE, you will see that the values in the map are all sorted based on age because the Person class overrides the compareTo method in a way that objects are compared based on age only. Now is there a way that I can make this further dynamic. Like can I change the value on which comparison happens for e.g. lets say I want to compare based on name, height, lastname as well.

Comment: You cannot sort a `HashMap`; it has no notion of order

Comment: @fge I am talking about extra logic that gives us that behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sortByComparator` method creates an implementation of `Comparator` that relies on the `Comparable` implementation of the Person class. Instead, you can pass any `Comparator` to your `sortByComparator`, and each passed `Comparator` can sort by different criteria.

```
private static Map<String, Person> sortByComparator(Map<String, Person> unsortMap, Comparator<Person> cmp, final boolean order)
{

    List<Entry<String, Person>> list = new LinkedList<>(unsortMap.entrySet());

    // Sorting the list based on values
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Person>>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Person> o1, Entry<String, Person> o2)
        {
            if (order)
            {
                return cmp.compare(o1.getValue(),o2.getValue());
            }
            else
            {
                return cmp.compare(o2.getValue(),o1.getValue());
            }
        }
    });

    // Maintaining insertion order with the help of LinkedList
    Map<String, Person> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, Person> entry : list)
    {
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return sortedMap;
}
```

Comment: My current logic takes the following Comparator "new Comparator<Entry<String, Person>>()" How can I further send a Comparator Object that implements Person class differently

Comment: @kapilchhattani See my edit. You should pass to your `sortByComparator` an instance of a class that implements `Comparator<Person>` and use that Comparator in your Comparator<Entry<String, Person>>

Comment: So the cmp is the object that will be the comparator.. Let me try this. If this works this will actually be a blessing..

Answer (score 0):

A sorted HashMap makes no sense, and it will break the hashing algorithm. If you want a map which is sorted, you should consider using a TreeMap instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
TreeMap<Integer, String> hm=new TreeMap();
hm.put(3, "arun singh");
hm.put(5, "vinay singh");
hm.put(1, "bandagi singh");
hm.put(6, "vikram singh");
hm.put(2, "panipat singh");
hm.put(28, "jakarta singh");

ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList(hm.values());
Collections.sort(al, new myComparator());

System.out.println("//sort by values \n");
for(String obj: al){
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> map2:hm.entrySet()){
        if(map2.getValue().equals(obj)){
            System.out.println(map2.getKey()+" "+map2.getValue());
        }
    } 
 }
}
}

class myComparator implements Comparator{
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
     String o3=(String) o1;
     String o4 =(String) o2;
return o3.compareTo(o4);
    }   
}
```

OUTPUT=

```
//sort by values 

3 arun singh
1 bandagi singh
28 jakarta singh
2 panipat singh
6 vikram singh
5 vinay singh
```